# Difference between sys.exit(app.exec_()) and app.exec_()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, sys

I am working with PySide and PyQt for GUI development. I have been using these codes to run a GUI application:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MyWin()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Accidentally I found if I replace `sys.exit(app.exec_())` with only `app.exec_()`, the program still works fine and it can exit correctly.
So what is the difference between these two? Is there a reason I should use `sys.exit(app.exec_())`?

Comment: In Python `sys.exit` is not necessary. However if you use it then you get the exit codes from Qt. Probably you don't care about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html), argument `arg` can be an integer giving the exit status. So return of [`app.exec_()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcoreapplication.html#exec) can tell `code exit status`. As the documentation for [`QCoreApplication.exit (int returnCode = 0)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcoreapplication.html#exit) says,

> By convention, a returnCode of 0 means success, and any non-zero value indicates an error.

So the reason is to tell Python  the code exit status from `PyQt`. If you avoid it, the program will close immediately.

Comment: This is not 100% correct. It is not to tell *Python* about the exit code, but the *parent process* (probably a shell like bash, or `explorer.exe`). To a parent process, a return code of `0` means that everything was okay. Anything else is considered an abnormal program termination. This can be important if you batch your application. But in GUI applications that's probably not the case and not very important. Maybe, in Windows you'll get notified about the event viewer about that. But I'm not sure about that. I'm not a Windows person ;)